# Stream on Map doesn't save .map changes

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream

Can someone explain me why the first code example doesn't save the changes I've made with .map on the Map but the second code example does?

First code example:

```
stringIntegerMap.entrySet().stream()
            .map(element -> element.setValue(100));
```

Second code example:

```
        stringIntegerMap.entrySet().stream()
            .map(element -> element.setValue(100))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Also, why does the second code example only print the values and not the whole element (key + value) ?

Comment: For the first question, read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html), particulary the section "Stream operations and pipelines". For the second question, look at what `Map.Entry::setValue` returns.

Answer (score 7):

Your stream operations are lazy-evaluated.

If you do not invoke a terminal operation such as `forEach` (or `collect`, etc.), the streaming never actually occurs, hence your `setValue` is not executed.

Note that modifying the collection/map you are streaming is generally advised against.

Finally, the API for `Map.Entry#setValue` is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html). 
You'll notice the method returns:

> old value corresponding to the entry

So, when you perform the map operation, the stream generated contains the values.

Some sources [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) (search for "stream operations and pipelines", and also the part about "non-interference" might help).

Comment: I hadn't noticed the `setValue` returning the old value within `Stream.map`, nice catch there.

Comment: What the OP apparently wants to achieve can be done entirely without the Stream API: `stringIntegerMap.replaceAll((k,v) -> 100); stringIntegerMap.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 1):

Streams are composed of a source, intermediate operations and terminal operations.

The terminal operations start the pipeline processing by lazily gathering elements from the source, then applying intermediate operations and finally executing the terminal operation.

`Stream.map` is an intermediate operation, whereas `Stream.forEach` is terminal. So in your first snippet the pipeline processing never starts (hence intermediate operations are never executed), because there's no terminal operation. When you use `forEach` in your 2nd snippet, then all the pipeline is processed.

Please take a look at the [`java.util.stream` package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) docs, where there's extensive information about streams and how to use them properly (i.e. you shouldn't modify the source of the stream from within intermediate or final operations, such as you're doing in `Stream.map`).

**Edit:**

As to your final question:

> why does the second code example only print the values and not the whole element (key + value) ?

[Mena's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48282925/1876620) explains it well: `Map.Entry.setValue` not only sets the given value to the entry, but also returns the old value. As you're using `Map.Entry.setValue` in a lambda expression within the `Stream.map` intermediate operation, you're actually transforming each `Map.Entry` element of the stream into the value it had before setting a new value. So, what arrives to `Stream.forEach` are the old values of the map, while the map has new values set by means of the *side-effect* produced by `Map.Entry.setValue`.